# BigRquery will not connect and the error message is blank

Tags: r, google-bigquery, rstudio-server

I'm trying to make use of the 'bigrquery' library in R to connect R to our big query databases. When I run this on a locally installed copy of R studio I don't have any problems, but when I'm running it on a server running R Studio Server I get a strange error message from the query_exec command.  I will paste the code below:

```
library(bigrquery)
project = 'projectIdentifier'
sql <- "SELECT * FROM [bradWorking.bradTempTable] WHERE f0_ >= '2015-10-22' AND f0_ <= '2015-11-01'"
data <- query_exec(query = sql, project=project, max_pages = Inf, destination_table = 'bradWorking.bradTempTable2')
Error:
```

I have never seen an error before that simply states 'Error'. Does anyone have any suggestions for ways to figure out what's going on?  Could this be related to the libssl that I'm using?

Here's the system information from R

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_CA.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_CA.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] bigrquery_0.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.1.0      magrittr_1.5    R6_2.1.2       
 [4] assertthat_0.1  parallel_3.2.3  DBI_0.3.1      
 [7] tools_3.2.3     dplyr_0.4.3     curl_0.9.5     
 [10] Rcpp_0.12.3     jsonlite_0.9.19 openssl_0.9.1
```

Thanks

Comment: No, that's a typo that was created when removing the actual project name.  That's not the problem.  The command wouldn't have executed if that was the bug because all the code after that would have waited for an end quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very familiar with bigrquery, but it looks like this could be an incompatibility between bigrquery and httr 1.1.0: https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery/issues/86

Answer (score 1):

rolling back httr as per https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery/issues/86 worked for me when i experienced this error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is useful but I'm getting the same error on a query of mine that's been running perfectly for the past couple months. Not sure if the issue is on the Google or R side