# bigrquery error after authentication

Tags: r, authentication, google-bigquery

I get the following error notification when i try to access bigquery from R installed on my windows 10 desktop machine.  Please can someone help.

> library(devtools)
>   library(assertthat)
>   library(bigrquery)
>
> project <- "jellyfish-gap" # put your project ID here
>   sql <- "SELECT year, month, day, weight_pounds FROM [publicdata:samples.natality] LIMIT 5"
>   query_exec(sql, project = project)
>   Use a local file to cache OAuth access credentials between R sessions?
>   1: Yes
>   2: No
>
> Selection: 2 Waiting for authentication in browser... Press Esc/Ctrl +
>   C to abort Authentication complete. Error: 
>   >

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with bigrquery, but it looks like this could be an incompatibility between bigrquery and httr 1.1.0: https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery/issues/86

See also this other SO question: [BigRquery will not connect and the error message is blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213880/bigrquery-will-not-connect-and-the-error-message-is-blank)

Comment: Thank you so much Danny -rolling back httr and reauthourizing wked - very very pleased :-)